# search through unsaved objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

If I have a group of objects, which are not yet in the database, how can I look for them?

My situation looks like this:

```
@base_object = BaseObject.new
@tiny_little_object = @base_object.tiny_little_objects.build
@tiny_little_object.name = "Jake"
@tiny_little_object = @base_object.tiny_little_objects.build
@tiny_little_object.name = "Finn"
```

So I have bunch of initialized objects, nothing special. Now I would like to be able to do this:

```
#### Yes, rails 3 here, find_by_name    
@base_object.tiny_little_objects.find_by_name("Jake")
```

But all I get is an empty array. How can I solve this problem, is there some elegant way other than just iteration and comparison?

Comment: this is for testing?  If you're a bit more specific about what you want to do it might help to answer your question

Comment: Your question smells of bad code design.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: i simply need to work on those objects before saving them, answer with 'detect' is obvious, i thikn im a little tired:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find_by_name` searches the database, so it will never return records that haven't been saved.  However, when you use build, the objects are stored in memory, associated with the base object.  So you should be able to find one with

```
@base_object.tiny_little_objects.detect{|obj| obj.name == "Jake"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [standard Ruby](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) - those are in a collection after all:

```
jakes = @base_object.tiny_little_objects.select { | object | object.name == 'Jake' }
```